# How to reference the latest Stream of a DynamoDB table in a Cloudformation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I am writing a plugin for the serverless framework, which references a DynamoDB Stream by its ARN. I can construct the DynamoDB tables ARN with the information I have at hand, but I don't know the timestamp part, that would be necessary to build the full stream ARN. I don't have access to the original DynamoDB Cloudformation definition, when I need to reference the Stream ARN, those two things can happen in entirely different templates. All I have is the ARN of the already created DynamoDB at this point.

Is there a way to reference the latest stream via a variable similar to  `arn:aws:dynamodb:${AWS::Region}::${AWS::AccountId}:table/eventbus-test/stream/${LATEST}`?

Or can I build it in another way by means of a serverless configuration or Cloudformation template?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this ?

Answer (score 7):

[According to the doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-dynamodb-table.html). You can access it with the `Fn::GetAtt` intrinsic function with the `StreamArn` parameter. For example:

```
Resources: 
  Table:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties:
      AttributeDefinitions:
      - AttributeName: leaseKey
        AttributeType: S
      KeySchema:
      - KeyType: HASH
        AttributeName: leaseKey
      ProvisionedThroughput:
        ReadCapacityUnits: '1'
        WriteCapacityUnits: '1'
Outputs:
  TableStreamArn:
    Value: !GetAtt Table.StreamArn
```

Comment: Thanks Laurent for your answer. Unfortunately, I don't have access to the original DynamoDB Cloudformation definition, when I need to reference the Stream ARN, those two things can happen in entirely different templates. All I have is the ARN of the already created DynamoDB at this point.

Comment: I understand, I suggest you update the question to reflect that. I'll leave my answer as is, it may help someone else.

Comment: For future folks, this only works if you have the resource in the same CloudFormation template

Comment: For future folks, this doesn't work as is and in order to access this attribute `You must specify the StreamSpecification property to use this attribute.` which documentation [is available here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-dynamodb-streamspecification.html). Otherwise you'll get `Attribute: StreamArn was not found for resource`

Comment: In my case, I'm dealing with an existing table/stream so I pass the needed Arn in through a template parameter.

Comment: Please assume you don't define the table resource here as that is the more common case.

Answer (score 0):

You may need a custom resource to do this. Your custom resource can use API to get the stream ARN and return it.